# Compositer per frame

Tags: compositing-nodes

I'm making an animation that uses a muzzle flare/flash. Obviously using cycles' emission shader is good but doesn't have the proper halo around the mesh. If I were to use the compositor to add the halo, would I have to do it for every frame?

Comment: You could just render that flash frame with the compositor effect and replace the original rendered frame.

Comment: Add a glare node in the compositor, and animate the values for it so that the effect is limited to the frames you need.